# Retry Exception Implementation in Current Scrapy and ScrapyPlaywright Version

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-playwright

I'm working with the latest versions of Scrapy (2.10.0) and ScrapyPlaywright (0.0.29) and trying to incorporate a `Retry_Exceptions` into my project. Unfortunately, my previous approach from an older Scrapy (2.8.0) and Scrapy-Playwright (0.0.26) version no longer seems effective. In the past, I could use the following code snippet:

```
Middleware.EXCEPTIONS_TO_RETRY += (PlaywrightTimeoutError,)
```

However, this method doesn't seem to work anymore. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some guidance or assistance on how to achieve the `Retry_Exceptions` functionality in the current setting file. Your help would be highly valued!